# C# calculating the next three cron performances

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, execution

To take first cron execution i use something like this:

```
var schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse("*/5 * * * *");
return schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
```

This statement return next cron exeution in DateTime type and information like this "Cron next execution at 14:00".

After that, I would like to calculate and receive information about the next two executions.

For example, if first will execute at 14:00, I would to return two DateTime which execute about 14:05 and 14:10.

Can someone can help with this?

Comment: what is return type of `schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);` method? is it `DateTime`?

Comment: What type is `schedule` -- a `CrontabSchedule` object? Can you post the definition of `CrontabSchedule`, specifically the properties and the list of methods?

Comment: Yes, this id DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You can add 5 and 10 mins respectively to the returning value of `schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);` method,

```
//Type of currentExecutionTime variable is DateTime
var currentExecutionTime = schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
var nextExecutionTime = currentExecutionTime.AddMinutes(5);
var nextToNextExecutionTime = currentExecutionTime.AddMinutes(10);
```

Comment: That sound good, but i must do this more programmatically, because cron expression can be executed every 5 minutes, hours or even day.

Comment: Can you elaborate `programmatically` here?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I did not understand what you said in the first comment -> That sound good, *but i must do this more programmatically,*. I just want clarification on it, so I asked what is mean by `programmatically` over here

Comment: I have list of cron expression, some execute at every 5 minutes, some over hour, and some one at least once in month, and i searching uniq way do this.